# How can I add the current date to my database table using php

Tags: php, mysql, database, date, phpmyadmin

The user will adds information into a textbox. when they click send the information is added to the database table using this php code:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO mytable (id, number, date)
VALUES ('', '$_POST[number]', 'date(1)')";
```

The 'id' is auto-id from phpmyadmin settings so its left blank. I want the current date to also display in the table as well.

I though by putting in date(1) to get the date would work but it doesn't seem to. 
Any ideas?

I set the date column in phpmyadmin to receive a date. So when I set the code to:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO mytable (id, number, date)
VALUES ('', '$_POST[number]', '')";
```

it just gives me 0000-00-00 in my table.
Any ideas how to fix this? so I can get the current date?

Comment: Mysql function `NOW()`

Comment: Also if `id` is auto_increment column, no need to put it in a query: `$sql = "INSERT INTO `mytable` (`number`, `date`)
VALUES ('$_POST[number]', NOW())";`. And also this code is vulnerable to SQL-injection attack, use proper escaping functions of your database layer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Mysql` `NOW()`:-

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO mytable (number, date) VALUES ('".$_POST['number']."', NOW())";//check the quotes too
```

Note:-

1.I hope `id` is `PRIMARY AUTO-INCREMENTED` value so no need to pass it.

2.Also this code is vulnerable to SQL-injection.Read `PHP` `mysqli_*` or `PDO` along with `prepared statements` to prevent from it.

Answer (score 1):

By enclosing it in single quotes, you are actually passing a string value.  You can either use [MYSQL now()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now) or set a [default](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/data-type-defaults.html) value for the column to supply a date automatically if one is not supplied.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO mytable (number, date)
VALUES ('". $_POST['number'] ."', NOW())";
```

Take note of the quotes around the `$_POST['number']` as this also goes back to the issue stated above.  You want to make sure that you are escaping the values properly, otherwise, strings will be passed instead of the desired values.